# CSV file - handle row and columns with python

Tags: python, file, csv, row, multiple-columns

Could you help me, please?

I have  CSV  dataset file about hotels and contain many columns. I need to handle hotel-name and reviews.

How to convert hotel-name rows to columns ? to combine reviews for each hotel and save the output into the new CSV file?

I use Python 3.7

Update: first thank you for comments

and I'm sorry, I have to supposed put the shape of the output

I have more than 1400 hotels

```
hotel-name     reviews 
Hotel Arena    love it
Hotel Arena    great
Hotel Arena    good
Hotel Arena    ........

the output will be :

hotel 1   hotel 2  hotel 3  .......
love it   stay     not bad
great     old      ..... 
good      ...      .......
..        
...         
....
```

Comment: Provide your question with the input, your code, problems you faced, and the expected output. Stack Overflow is not a place to get a free code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a csv file that contains many rows, each row has a review of a hotel.

If so you can use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'hotel': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'rating': [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]})

df.groupby('hotel').aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

The DF output is:

```
  hotel  rating
0     A       1
1     A       1
2     B       2
3     B       4
4     A       3
5     C       5
```

And after the group by:

```
          rating
hotel           
A      [1, 1, 3]
B         [2, 4]
C            [5]
```

You will have to install pandas for this, and [read your csv file with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (which is very easy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do that. Assuming a csv file like this one:

```
name,review,comments
A,nice,blabla
B,notnice,bleble
```

You can filter the rows by columns:

```
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = open('file.csv', 'rb')
    for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter = ','):
        print (row['name'],row['review'])
```

Printing:

```
('A', 'nice')
('B', 'notnice')
```